# Does a US permanent resident need a visa for Ireland?

Tags: visas, ireland, us-residents

I am a US permanent resident and I have a Form I-131 travel document. I want to visit Ireland. Can I enter Ireland with these, or am I required to apply for a visa?

Comment: Form I-131 is for **applying for** one of _several different kinds_ of non-passport travel documents. If you only have the I-131 itself, that will certainly not help you; if you have had a document issued based on a I-131 application, then you need to tell us which kind it is. Please also tell us what your nationality is, and if you hold a valid passport for that nationality.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Answer (score 4):

The entry requirements to Ireland are determined by your nationality. Neither I-327 (permit to reenter), nor I-571 (refugee travel document) grants you any specific rights with regards to being admissible to Ireland.

So, the answer to your question “Can I enter Ireland with these, or am I required to apply for a visa?” is, “That is determined by the national passport you carry.” If you do not carry a national passport, both I-571 and I-327 require a visa.

Comment: I don't know anything about those numbered forms, but OP mentioned 131, whereas you've answered with regard to 327 and 571. If 131 doesn't have anything to do with the problem, maybe you should mention it, like [@Henning did](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100102/does-a-us-permanent-resident-need-a-visa-for-ireland#comment240498_100102)? Again if my comment is just a nonsense, because I'm not the domain expert, just tell me that it's nonsense :)

Comment: I-327 and I-571 are two most common travel documents based on properly filed I-131. Probably, the only forms issued for LPRs by filing I-131

Comment: @gdrt, OP mentions `Form I-131 travel document`. I mentioned 2 most common relevant (for LPRs) ones.

Comment: +1. Thanks for clarification, maybe it's worth to add it to the answer and then get rid of the comments?

Comment: You might also want to consider form I-551, the green card itself.

Comment: I-551 is not a `Form I-131 travel document`

Answer (score 2):

Your country of residence is mostly irrelevant for traveling to third countries; so is your Green Card: the US government gave you a document, why would you assume it has *any meaning* to the government of another, independent country, here Ireland?

What you need to enter Ireland depends on *your nationality*, which is shown by your passport. You didn't specify that, so there is no way to answer this.

Having a Green Card *can* help to positively influence a visa decision, because many countries consider the underlying decisions of the US a worthwhile input, but it doesn't bestow any rights outside the US.

Comment: A green card does allow visa free entry to several countries, most notably Canada.

Comment: @phoog Visa-free, and to Canada, passport-free too - it's all you Need unless travelling by air